# PHP Tool to check syntax/code validity

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and was wondering whether there is a tool which checks the PHP code syntax and validity.

For example if I have:

```
class myClass
{
    public function function1()
    {
        $this->myvariable++;
        $this->function2();
    }

    private $myVariable;
}
```

I would like the tool to highlight that the variable `myvariable` and the function `function2` does not exist within that class.

I have searched online and found http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/index.html however when I tried it in my PHP project it did not work correctly. I know that php has the -l option, however that only checks for syntax not validity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For every code there is an IDE.  PHPStorm is a popular paid one.  Netbeans is a popular free one.

Comment: That's good to know about. I've been using notepad++ on a PHP project for the last bit and have been looking for an upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an IDE.

[PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is a popular paid IDE for PHP. (~99$/~99€)

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html) is also popular, as well as being free.

I've also heard of [phpDesigner](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php), [Komodo IDE](http://komodoide.com/), and [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio). Also, you can find a list of PHP Editors [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_editors).

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for Integrated Development Environment or shortly IDE, which is software with a lot built in functions to help you to write, test, develop, debug etc... your software.

If we are talking about PHP programming language I prefer them in the following order:

- [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/)
- [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)
- [phpDesigner](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php)
- [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio)

Answer (score 1):

The kind of tool you're looking for, strictly speaking, is a static analysis tool such as [PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/). An even simpler (and faster) check can be run from PHP itself using the `-l` switch, but will only warn against syntax errors.

More advanced checks against *code smells*,  which are somewhat less than bugs but have been found to often evolve into those, can be run by tools such as [CodeSniffer for PHP](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer).

That said, the tools above (and many more) are either already bundled, or can be easily integrated, into various IDEs such as [Eclipse for PHP](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/lunasr2). These also supply useful integrations such as code highlighting and inline error highlighting, so that you can quickly "zoom in" on the various bugs. Also, they come with a ton of useful features such as code completion, lookups, insight, templating, and refactoring. [More advanced IDEs](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php) also "know" about the most popular frameworks and so can be a great help in using them.